# Creating a VSAN datastore

Tags: vmware-vsphere, high-availability, vmware-vsan, vsan

I am trying to set up my first HA cluster and I have some hard time digging into VSAN datastores.

I have two ESXi hosts both with two 480 SSD hard drives in RAID 1

Can I add the existing hosts' disks to VSAN datastore? As far as I know, the ESXi can't boot from VSAN datastore. What would you recommend in my situation?

Answer (score 7):

Move/reinstall ESXi to USB flash drives, one per each host. In that case, ESXi boots from the USB drive, so local storage is free to be used for VSAN.

Use this guide to setup VMware VSAN https://storagehub.vmware.com/t/vmware-vsan/vsan-2-node-guide/ Note, you need a third host to set up a witness.

For the case, you can also set up free VSAN like solution, StarWind Virtual SAN. It works from just two hosts, no witness is required. Corresponding guide https://www.starwindsoftware.com/resource-library/starwind-virtual-san-for-vsphere-installation-and-configuration-guide